# Is there a grammatical case indicating displacement?

Tags: grammar, cases

As part of a constructed language experiment I am trying to write phrases with clause structure of [noun supersedes noun] as just two words. For example, “death before dishonor” or “freedom over tyranny.” I do not think the ablative case would make sense in this context.

I suppose this could also apply to a clause like [noun, not noun] or [verb this, not that].

Comment: "Prepositions are arbitrary" applies here too.

Comment: Note that there is now also a conlang stackexchange here: [conlang.se]

Answer (score 1):

In a constructed language, you are free to do what you want, and you can create a case with case inflections for this use case.

I am not sure whether this kind of case occurs in any natural language and whether it has been named by linguists before, but in Finnish there are two cases, the [Essive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essive_case) and the [Translative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translative_case) case that come close to it.

Comment: I think the aversive/evitative case found in Australian Aboriginal languages might be close to the case I am thinking of. I don’t know enough to determine whether that is accurate.